# Getting weird response while making POST request to reCAPTCHA server to validate the token

Tags: javascript, recaptcha-v3

In the frontend of my app I get reCAPTCHA-v3 token after user fills up the form, the system takes this token and from the backend (meteor.js) it sends POST request to reCAPTCHA server to validate the token.
My goal is to validate the token and proceed depending on the score but I get response like this of which I am not aware of. What should i do ? (Note : I have used the same payload and url from postman where i get response as expected )

{ ok:false, redirected:false, status:0, statusText:"", type:"opaque" , url: "" }

I am using this method to send POST request.

```
async function determineVulnerability (token) {
    const SECRET_KEY = <SECRET_KEY>;
    const url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    
    try {   
        const settings = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                secret: SECRET_KEY,
                response: token,
            }),
        };

        const apiResponse = await fetch(url, settings);       
        return apiResponse;

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"What should i do ?"_ - first of all, go read [ask] and [mre], please. You need to _show us_ what you are actually doing, instead of giving us only an ever-so-vague verbal description.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i have updated the description as you said

Comment: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and a request body that gets populated with JSON, don't match.

Comment: I also ran into this, as per the Google reCaptcha documentation, the validation must occur on the Server side. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify